# Electron frame: false not working on Raspberry Pi 3 model B

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, electron, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

Usually when I use `frame: false`, on a platform like Windows it hides the frame on top of the window as well as the buttons. I really like this functionality and I'd like to use it on my Raspberry Pi running raspbian.

I have updated `NPM` to it's latest version. I've also tried `--enable-transparent-visuals --disable-gpu` but it didn't seem to work. Anyway, here is my current main.js:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

let win;

function createWindow () {

  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});


  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true,
    frame: false
  }));


  win.webContents.openDevTools();

  win.on('closed', () => {

    win = null;
  })
}


app.on('ready', createWindow);


app.on('window-all-closed', () => {

  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {

  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
```

And here is my package.js:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.6.11"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error, it was a typo. The frame: false should obviously be in the initialization of the window.